# junit test results in tfs

Tags: junit, nunit, mstest, xunit

How to make TFS 2010 show junit test results, that were generated by third-party tool? If it can't, probably, there is a way to convert junit report to xunit/nunit/mstest report. It would be also great! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to publish Junit tests during TFS-Build you can make use of [TFS Build Extension Power Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2d7c8577-54b8-47ce-82a5-8649f579dcb6/).
In there you can find a set of XSLT transforms from JUnit output into TRX. Employing TFS-Build to upload TRX should from then be possible.

Comment: It works great for me! Now it can be much easier to publish test results, especially using [msxsl.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714) to transform test.xml to test.trx