# Team foundation server not showing Junit results

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, tfs

Currently working with Team foundation server, coding in java, using eclipse plugin for TFS, and maven for the builds.

The problem I am having is that the test results in my maven build don't seem to appear on TFS when I look through the build log. Is there some special syntax the POM file needs to display Junit test results into the build log in TFS?

All I get is zero test runs.

Summary

**Debug | Any CPU**

0 error(s), 0 warning(s)

$/Skip Vendor Management/SkipManagement/pom.xml compiled

No test results

No code coverage results

Comment: Do you have a working maven build which reports results of the tests via `mvn clean package`?

Comment: I get a successful maven build that reports the test results via maven clean package. 

The edit I made above giving the summary of the results is from the TFS build.

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert the test results to a .trx file and call a command to push them into TFS.

See: [junit test results in tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10584017/junit-test-results-in-tfs)

Comment: I've seen this answer before, but it doesn't specify how to accomplish this. How do I convert them to .trx files, and what command do I use to push them to TFS?